# Laravel Eloquent : Getting object instead of array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Trying to get a hotel in detail for hotel management API, in which for some hotels, getting

> $hotel->rooms

as object and for some as array. The eloquent query in Hotel model as below.

```
public function detail($hotelid) { 
    return $this->with(['rooms','roomType'])->find($hotelid);
}

public function rooms() {
    return $this->hasMany(HotelRooms::class, 'hotels_id')->where('status','active');
}
```

HotelRoom Model

```
public function roomType(){
   return $this->hasOne(RoomType::class,'id','room_type_id')->where('status','active');
}
```

Controller

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->model = new Hotel();
}

public function hotelDetail(Request $request){

    $data = $this->model->detail($request->input('hotel_id'));

    foreach($data->rooms as $key=>$room){

        if(!$room->roomType){
            unset($data->rooms[$key]);
            continue;
        }

    }

    return response()->json([
         'status' => true,
         'status_message' => 'successful',
         'data' => $data,
    ]);
}
```

response

```
{
    "id":"id",
    "name":"name",
    "rooms":{
        "1":{},
        "2":{}
    }       
}
```

```
{
    "id":"id",
    "name":"name",
    "rooms":[
        {},
        {},
    ]       
}
```

Comment: Which on you got? and which on you expect?

Comment: I got both in response. For example, for hotel-1 I got the first response, and for hotel-2 got the second one. I prefer the second response @hoseinz3

Comment: Please share your rooms relation definition

Comment: I have added in question please check. @hoseinz3

Comment: Please can you add your controller method?

Comment: do you have any filtering in your response?

Comment: added @RossWilson

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, can you add all the code for the method?

Comment: @hoseinz3 Yes I am having, but even getting same kind of response after removing those.

Comment: I think in the detail method you have tried some filtering, after use `filter` method you should add `values` method to re-index response

Comment: Can you please explain me , How to do that @hoseinz3

Comment: Added , Please check now @RossWilson, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `unset` on array, your array indexes remain for each item. Same as for `collection->filter()` or for `array_filter()` that is actually used in `collection->filter()`. That is why you need to rebuild the indexes:

```
$data->rooms = array_values($data->rooms->toArray());
```

to reindex the array.

Or use the `foreach`, but push values to new array:

```
$filteredRooms = [];
   foreach($data->rooms as $key=>$room){

        if(!$room->roomType){
           continue;
        }
        $filteredRooms[] = $room;

    }

$data->rooms = $filteredRooms;
```

Or instead of `foreach` loop, use `filter` for collection in combination with `values()` :

```
$filteredRooms = $data->rooms->filter(function ($room, $key) {
    return (!$room->roomType)? false : true;
})->values();
```

Comment: ```... "rooms": {
            "1": {
                "id": 2,...```

Comment: @NoName, did you try with `toArray()`?

Comment: Yeah, Tried out. same response.

Comment: @NoName, can you test filter in combination with values() ? I have edited my answer

Comment: Can we have this inside **foreach** Is that correct method ?

Comment: @NoName, this replaces foreach. You can reassign value to `$data->rooms = $filteredRooms` after

Comment: ```$data->rooms = array_values($data->rooms->toArray());``` tested this one @nikalz

Comment: @NoName, so did that worked? I have added another solution in answer

Comment: this one works ```unset($data->rooms);
   $data->rooms = $fileteredRooms;``` after foreach. Where in foreach ```$filteredRooms[]=$room```.

Comment: Why did this happen?

Comment: when you use unset, your array indexes remain for each item, same as for collection->filter() or for array_filter() that is actually used in collection->filter(). That is why you need to rebuild the indexes either way suggested in the answer above

Answer (score 1):

After filtering array you have to re-index your array.

```php
foreach($data->rooms as $key=>$room){

    if(!$room->roomType){
        unset($data->rooms[$key]);
        continue;
    }
}
$data->rooms = $data->rooms->values();
```

Comment: getting same response

Comment: but getting as array when the last line added inside foreach, is that correct format ?